# How to debug random reboots, with no kernel panic, of an embedded system?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, reboot, crash, random

I have two [aValue RPC-10W1](http://www.avalue.com.tw/en/product/detail.aspx?ccid=2&cid=12&id=81&zid=762) embedded systems that reboots by themselves after 1-2 hours.

Facts:

- The board will reboot within a time span of 1 to 2½ hours.
- The issue is present on two identical systems.
- The issue is present using aValue's own Linux firmware (Ubuntu 10.04).
- The issue is present with nothing other than power supply connected.
- The board is using Linux kernel 2.6.35.3.
- No kernel panic is shown in terminal. The Linux terminal is directed to a serial port at bootup.
- No warnings or errors are shown from `dmesg`.

Things I've tried:

- Different root file systems:

  - Stock Ubuntu 10.04 from aValue.
  - Custom minimal file system created using LTIB. In aValue's user manual they describe how to use LTIB for their board.
- Compile my own kernel using the kernel sources supplied from aValue (came on a CD).

Things I haven't tried:

- Check if the issue is present on their Android or WinCE releases.

I've compared the Linux kernel source I received from aValue with the Freescale kernel source and they are the same + a huge single patch file from aValue.

How can I proceed to determine what is causing these reboots?

Comment: If it is easy to confirm that this is a linux issue (ruling out broken hardware) by testing with one of the other releases then you should do that.

Comment: You should also look at the logs to see if this is a clean reboot -- i.e., something has triggered the kernel.  Find the kernel messages indicating the boot (these will likely  have a `[    0.000000]` timestamp; in `less` search `\[\s+0.00`) and look at what happened right before that.  There should be clear indications that the system is shutting down (services stopping, etc. -- you can always do a real reboot and look at the log for that if you are not sure).  If not, it was triggered by the hardware for some reason.

Comment: @goldilocks I will try the Android and WinCE releases as soon as I can.
I will also take a look in any logs I can find, but IIRC there were no warnings or errors there.

Comment: **I am not referring to warnings or errors.**  Read that comment again ;) If the system rebooted because the power fluctuated, or for some other hardware oriented issue, the system will not have shut down properly, and that **will be clear** because the shutdown is *missing from the log*.  **Otherwise**, there will be a record of the shutdown; it does not have to contain any errors, it's just what normally happens. *The system logs a shutdown.* As already mentioned, you can get an example of this by doing a proper reboot or halt. It is either one way, or the other, and *there is a difference*.

Comment: `/var/log/messages` and/or `/var/log/syslog` should contain this information.  Read my earlier comment about exactly what to look for.

Comment: @goldilocks Ah, now I see what you mean. The logs weren't present on my minimal fs, but I'll take a look at the logs of an Ubuntu release and update my post. IIRC, the last time I checked the logs (maybe a month ago) these reboots were not logged.

Comment: It's like something just flipped the power switch off and on again. We though the hardware was bad and just now received another unit, which also showed the same kind of reboot behavior.

Comment: Any chance you have a software watchdog running? In case the kernel gets overloaded (classical example would be sudden network activity spikes lasting longer than the watchdog timeout) this could manifest itself in the described manner (i.e. no messages whatsoever in the log, if the watchdog doesn't generate those for some reason).

Answer (score 2):

I guess I could say that I solved this problem.

I downloaded `Mfgtools-Rel-1.6.2.042-Linux-Android-V11.zip` from aValue's homepage and used the pre-compiled kernel in that archive instead of the one from the supplied CD and the problem went away. The creation date of the new kernel was a few months later than the rebooting kernel so I guess aValue solved this problem and published it on their homepage.

I haven't seen any changelog and neither have I bothered to compare any source code to see what caused this problem. I cant even remember if the Mfgtools archive supplied source code.